# Laravel timestamp (from json response) is different from the one that generated from the artisan & mysql select command

Tags: php, laravel

TL;DR: There is no `2020-08-09` in the json response.

I just found a weird behavior in my `Laravel 7.x` project today. As mentioned on the title above, the `created_at` and `updated_at` of json response is different from the one generated from artisan command.

The problem appears when I change the default timezone in `app/config.php` from `UTC` to `Asia/Jakarta`. To make it clear, here is some result of my queries:

`mysql> select * from field_reports`

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------+-------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | company_id | branch_id | user_id | title       | chronology             | images                                     | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+-------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |          1 |         1 |       1 | example     | example chronology     | [{"url": "some_url", "path": "some_path"}] | 2020-08-08 16:02:53 | 2020-08-08 16:29:46 |
|  2 |          1 |         1 |       1 | new fr      | new chronology         | [{"url": "some_url", "path": "some_path"}] | 2020-08-08 18:31:32 | 2020-08-08 18:31:32 |
|  3 |          1 |         1 |       1 | new fr      | new chronology         | [{"url": "some_url", "path": "some_path"}] | 2020-08-08 18:32:48 | 2020-08-08 18:32:48 |
|  4 |          1 |         1 |       1 | example     | example chronology     | [{"url": "some_url", "path": "some_path"}] | 2020-08-09 01:33:31 | 2020-08-09 01:33:31 |
|  5 |          1 |         1 |       1 | NEW         | NEW CHRONOLOGY         | [{"url": "some_url", "path": "some_path"}] | 2020-08-09 01:44:41 | 2020-08-09 01:44:41 |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+-------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

`php artisan tinker`

```php
>>> App\User::first()->fieldReports;
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4033
     all: [
       App\FieldReport {#4035
         id: 2,
         company_id: 1,
         branch_id: 1,
         user_id: 1,
         title: "new fr",
         chronology: "new chronology",
         images: "[{"url": "some_url", "path": "some_path"}]",
         created_at: "2020-08-08 18:31:32",
         updated_at: "2020-08-08 18:31:32",
       },
       App\FieldReport {#4038
         id: 3,
         company_id: 1,
         branch_id: 1,
         user_id: 1,
         title: "new fr",
         chronology: "new chronology",
         images: "[{"url": "some_url", "path": "some_path"}]",
         created_at: "2020-08-08 18:32:48",
         updated_at: "2020-08-08 18:32:48",
       },
       App\FieldReport {#4039
         id: 4,
         company_id: 1,
         branch_id: 1,
         user_id: 1,
         title: "example",
         chronology: "example chronology",
         images: "[{"url": "some_url", "path": "some_path"}]",
         created_at: "2020-08-09 01:33:31",
         updated_at: "2020-08-09 01:33:31",
       },
       App\FieldReport {#4040
         id: 5,
         company_id: 1,
         branch_id: 1,
         user_id: 1,
         title: "NEW",
         chronology: "NEW CHRONOLOGY",
         images: "[{"url": "some_url", "path": "some_path"}]",
         created_at: "2020-08-09 01:44:41",
         updated_at: "2020-08-09 01:44:41",
       },
     ],
   }
>>>
```

and this one from get request in POSTMAN, here is where the problem exist, please have a look at the timestamp:

```js
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "company_id": 1,
            "branch_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "title": "new fr",
            "chronology": "new chronology",
            "images": "[{\"url\": \"some_url\", \"path\": \"some_path\"}]",
            "created_at": "2020-08-08T11:31:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-08T11:31:32.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "company_id": 1,
            "branch_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "title": "new fr",
            "chronology": "new chronology",
            "images": "[{\"url\": \"some_url\", \"path\": \"some_path\"}]",
            "created_at": "2020-08-08T11:32:48.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-08T11:32:48.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "company_id": 1,
            "branch_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "title": "example",
            "chronology": "example chronology",
            "images": "[{\"url\": \"some_url\", \"path\": \"some_path\"}]",
            "created_at": "2020-08-08T18:33:31.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-08T18:33:31.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "company_id": 1,
            "branch_id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "title": "NEW",
            "chronology": "NEW CHRONOLOGY",
            "images": "[{\"url\": \"some_url\", \"path\": \"some_path\"}]",
            "created_at": "2020-08-08T18:44:41.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-08T18:44:41.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally, here is the script in the controller:
`FieldReportController.php`

```php
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $fieldReports = $request->user()->fieldReports;
    
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $fieldReports,
    ]);
}
```

I've tried several things like:

- Run `php artisan config:clear`
- Run `php artisan cache:clear`
- Run `php artisan route:clear`
- Run `valet restart`

But the problem is still there. Any clue?

Comment: I note there's a `Z` at the end for the resource. That means it's in the UTC timezone. What timezones are the other data in?

Comment: All of them have `Z` on it (fetched from postman, & flutter http service)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **Laravel 7** uses a new date serialization format when using the **toArray** or **toJson** method on Eloquent models. To format dates for serialization, the framework now uses Carbon's **toJSON** method, which produces an **ISO-8601** compatible date including timezone information and fractional seconds. In addition, this change provides better support and integration with client-side date parsing libraries.

Previously, dates would be serialized to a format like the following: **2020-12-02 20:01:00**. Dates serialized using the new format will appear like: **2020-12-02T20:01:00.283041Z**. Please note that **ISO-8601** dates are always expressed in **UTC**.

---

If you would like to keep using the previous behavior you can override the `serializeDate` method on your model :

```
use DateTimeInterface;

/**
 * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
 * @return string
 */
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

**Note** :This change only affects **serialization** of models and model collections to **arrays** and **JSON**. This change has **no effect** on how dates are stored in your database. 
See the [Upgrade Guide 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization)

Comment: What i do wrong with this code on laravel 8.50 but I take this error:  Declaration of App\Models\Action::serializeDate(App\Models\DateTimeInterface $date) should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date) {"userId":5,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Declaration of App\\Models\\Action::serializeDate(App\\Models\\DateTimeInterface $date) should be compatible with Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date) at C:\\OSPanel\\domains\
eports\\app\\Models\\Action.php:8)

Answer (score 0):

Inside model use

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

Comment: I think this is not a proper solution. It happens everywhere on every models. Also, the problem is not about formatting, it's a time gap.

Comment: Have you checked the timezone in your app?

Comment: I did, that's what I asked about.

Comment: This does not work, because the time does not match the server's