# Formats of TIMESTAMP values are different in JSON response

Tags: mysql, serialization, eloquent, timestamp, laravel-8

On my users table I have a joined_at column besides timestamps (created_at and updated_at) as MySQL TIMESTAMP columns.

I check the database table structure and definitions are exactly same:

[image]

The controller method for testing purpose is pretty simple:

```
public function user()
{
    return User::select('joined_at', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->first();
}
```

When I query a user through Postman, I get this as JSON response:

[image]

**As you can see, joined_at value is formatted differently from created_at and updated_at.**

Here, I am expecting the timestamps' format based on the answer in [Laravel timestamp (from json response) is different from the one that generated from the artisan & mysql select command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319391/laravel-timestamp-from-json-response-is-different-from-the-one-that-generated)

BUT joined_at doesn't comply with it. **I wonder why there is a difference like this.**

**NOTE:** I'm NOT looking for answer to correct the results by casting, I'm already doing that with serializeDate function. I want to know WHY there is a difference in formats between timestamp columns while they should all be in "2022-02-11T10:14:16.000000Z" format according to https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization

Answer (score 2):

You can cast values on your `model`

Check Docummentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

```
protected $casts = [
    'joined_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

Comment: I am using serializeDate function for casting already. What I'm wondering is when we don't use casting why there is a difference between formats of timestamp fields. I think they should be consistent ("2022-02-11T10:14:16.000000Z" format as described here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization), shouldn't they?

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that Laravel is ONLY transforming timestamps (created_at and updated_at) fields to ISO-8601 format ("2022-02-11T10:14:16.000000Z") in JSON response.

And serializeDate method ONLY affects these fields (created_at and updated_at) as well.

Maybe they have fixed this in later minor versions of Laravel, my version is 8.48 .