# Laravel Accessor to convert to UTC timezone doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I have this accessor in my model but doesn't seem to work:

```php
/**
     * @return ?Carbon
     */
    public function getStartAtUtcAttribute()
    {
        if (empty($this->start_at)) return null;

        $startAt = $this->start_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        return Carbon::parse($startAt)->timezone('UTC');
    }
```

result:

```
"start_at": "2022-11-09T03:00:00.000000Z", // this is saved as UTC. But in real world, it's on a specified timezone
"start_at_utc": "2022-11-09T03:00:00.000000Z",
```

they are still showing the same result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319391/laravel-timestamp-from-json-response-is-different-from-the-one-that-generated

Answer (score 0):

You would try 2 version
version 1.

```php
  public function getStartAtUtcAttribute(): string
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->start_at)->timezone('UTC')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
```

Version 2

```php
   protected $casts = [
        'start_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s'
    ];
```